# Saving ñ characters in Oracle 11g through JDBC

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, character-encoding, utf, utf8-decode

First of all, I did some research and this question has been asked a lot of times. The problem is when a String character with ñ is saved in the database, it becomes an unreadable special character (square symbols). When you read data via Java JDBC, it becomes another character (Ã‘). e.g. the character Señorita reads as SeÃ‘orita. UTF is not set in our database according to the admin. The weird thing is (and this is why I posted this question), when I use Oracle Toad to update the table data with string characters with ñ, it saves it as ñ in the table. It does not change to an unreadable special character unlike if I save or update it via JDBC. (e.g. Señorita reads as Señorita)

My boss says if this is possible via Toad, you can certainly do it in Java but I haven't been able to find a way. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the Java code you use for updating the db? Also, check the charset encoding of your database (or ask the DBA to check it) with `select value$ from sys.props$ where name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'`